# Kafka __consumer_offset segment deletion failed

Tags: apache-kafka

We attempted an upgrade of Kafka from 6.2.0 to 6.2.7 and started receiving these error messages in the upgraded broker logs. We reverted back the version upgrade and the error still continues.

```
Oct 29 11:50:02 kafka-server-start[2447]: [2022-10-29 11:50:02,558] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-36, dir=/opt/kafka-data0/kafka-logs] Deleting segment files LogSegment(baseOffset=0, size=311011, lastModifiedTime=0, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1667036391671)) (kafka.log.Log)
Oct 29 11:50:02 kafka-server-start[2447]: [2022-10-29 11:50:02,558] INFO Failed to delete log /opt/kafka-data0/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-36/00000000000000000000.log.deleted because it does not exist. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
Oct 29 11:50:02 kafka-server-start[2447]: [2022-10-29 11:50:02,558] INFO Failed to delete offset index /opt/kafka-data0/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-36/00000000000000000000.index.deleted because it does not exist. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
Oct 29 11:50:02 kafka-server-start[2447]: [2022-10-29 11:50:02,558] INFO Failed to delete time index /opt/kafka-data0/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-36/00000000000000000000.timeindex.deleted because it does not exist. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
```

In the zookeeper logs we see

```
Oct 29 07:51:04 zookeeper-server-start[2085]: [2022-10-29 07:51:04,581] WARN Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

I see the `.deleted` and `.cleaned` files appear/disappear in the partition directory

```
root@ip-xxx:/opt/kafka-data0/kafka-logs# ll __consumer_offsets-36/
total 392
drwxr-xr-x   2 kafka kafka     4096 Oct 29 11:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x 488 kafka kafka    40960 Oct 29 11:55 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka        8 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka   311011 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       12 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.timeindex
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka 10485760 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006355.index
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka      298 Oct 29 09:43 00000000000000006355.log
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       10 Oct 29 09:52 00000000000000006355.snapshot
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka 10485756 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006355.timeindex
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       10 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006357.snapshot
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka      250 Oct 29 11:07 leader-epoch-checkpoint
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       43 Oct 29 10:41 partition.metadata
```

```
root@ip-xxx:/opt/kafka-data0/kafka-logs# ll __consumer_offsets-36/
total 1168
drwxr-xr-x   2 kafka kafka     4096 Oct 29 11:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x 488 kafka kafka    40960 Oct 29 11:55 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka        8 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka        8 Oct 29 11:55 00000000000000000000.index.cleaned
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka   311011 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka   311011 Oct 29 11:55 00000000000000000000.log.cleaned
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       12 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.timeindex
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       12 Oct 29 11:55 00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka 10485760 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006355.index
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka      298 Oct 29 09:43 00000000000000006355.log
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       10 Oct 29 09:52 00000000000000006355.snapshot
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka 10485756 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006355.timeindex
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       10 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006357.snapshot
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka      250 Oct 29 11:07 leader-epoch-checkpoint
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       43 Oct 29 10:41 partition.metadata
```

```
root@ip-xxxx:/opt/kafka-data0/kafka-logs# ll __consumer_offsets-36/
total 704
drwxr-xr-x   2 kafka kafka     4096 Oct 29 11:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x 488 kafka kafka    40960 Oct 29 11:58 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka        8 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka        8 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.index.deleted
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka   311011 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka   311011 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.log.deleted
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       12 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.timeindex
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       12 Oct 29 09:39 00000000000000000000.timeindex.deleted
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka 10485760 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006355.index
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka      298 Oct 29 09:43 00000000000000006355.log
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       10 Oct 29 09:52 00000000000000006355.snapshot
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka 10485756 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006355.timeindex
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       10 Oct 29 10:51 00000000000000006357.snapshot
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka      250 Oct 29 11:07 leader-epoch-checkpoint
-rw-r--r--   1 kafka kafka       43 Oct 29 10:41 partition.metadata
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I suspect that missing ".snapshot" file for this 0000 segment may be the culprit.   I wonder if we can just create it manually to unblock the broker?